# Column headers not displayed for gnome apps

Tags: gnome, gtk, gtk3

My company has an Ubuntu server that's used by Windows users (among others) to run some linux apps through VNC sessions.  However, when these windows have columns of data with headers (to be precise, when there's a GtkTreeView widget with visible column headers), the headers "exist" in the sense that they take up space and are clickable and draggable, but they aren't rendered.

Here's what the "open file" dialogue box (in this case from gedit) looks like when running on this server:

[image]

For comparison, here's how it *should* look, with the column headers ("Name," "Size," "Modified") visible:

[image]

I've tried deleting my `~/.gtk` and `~/.gnome` directories as suggested on similar questions but to no avail.

**Version and Configuration Information**

The server's motd says

> Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)

I'm told this has also been replicated on a fresh Ubuntu 19 server install in a virtual machine (hence bypassing vnc and ruling that out as a problem), but I don't have immediate access to that to check what's going on.

The installed version of `libgtk-3` is `3.22.30-1ubuntu3`, which is the same as for the desktop I took the "correct" screenshot on.  (`gedit` is built against gtk3 according to `ldd`.)

I don't know what other version or config information is relevant to post, but I'll be happy to add more information if someone can tell me what to look at.